# Unity3D : Drawing line between three points that follows a 3Dmodel surface contours

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this scene that lets a user click on a 3D model point and instantiates a sphere point . After selecting three sphere points. I would like to draw a line that follows the surface contours of the 3D model connecting all three points. I have looked into Line render component but this will just draw a line between the points . I need the the line to follow the surface contours of the 3d model mesh. How could I do this?

[image]

Comment: You'll probably want need to implement your own bezier/quadratic curve renderer that matches the capsule's curve which you can get if you know the diameter. I don't believe that is natively supported by Unity's line renderer. I unfortunately don't have an implementation myself to present you, but there are some tutorials for it if you look up "Unity quadratic curve renderer"

Comment: Hi . Thanks for the reply. The capsule is just for testing but what if the model was a different mesh object?

Comment: More complex shapes (or shapes with sharp edges) would most likely become an issue i'm afraid.